# How to transfer data between SwiftNIO TCP-server and Python based TCP-client?

Tags: python, swift, tcp, client-server, swift-nio

I have a TCP server written in `SwiftNIO`, based on this [documentation](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76-tcp-server-with-the-swiftnio-networking-framework).

I want my client to be written in `python` from which I can send multiple `JSON` strings & can receive similar/different multiple `JSON` string(s) as a response periodically for a few minutes.

In which format do I need to convert those `JSON` strings from the `python` client & how do I get the same `JSON` string on the `SwiftNIO` server (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use HTTP using the [Vapor](https://vapor.codes) web server and any Python HTTP library such as [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). If you do that, then your job will be pretty straightforward. The Vapor community is also super helpful in their [Discord chat](http://vapor.team/).

If you really want to do this in a low-level library like SwiftNIO then that's of course possible but you'll need to design a so called "wire protocol" for the framing (ie. when does one JSON message start and end). SwiftNIO is very well equipped for these things but you'll likely need to learn a bunch of things.

You could for example use NIO Extras' [`LineBasedFrameDecoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-extras/blob/main/Sources/NIOExtras/LineBasedFrameDecoder.swift#L33) and send each JSON (make sure it doesn't contain newlines) followed by a `\n`. Or you could say that you prepend the JSON by say a 32 bit length field (which you could decode using the [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-extras/blob/main/Sources/NIOExtras/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.swift#L74). There are many options...

You could also implement [JSON-RPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org) and you could get some inside in [this example](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-examples/tree/main/json-rpc) which is also explained in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rlhlc6NaO4w).